# Terminal Run Code for n seconds

Tags: terminal, command

I've searched for this, but haven't found a single command yet - how would i run say hello.o for n amount of seconds on the terminal.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 watch -n 60 hello.o
```

If you want to run hello.o for n number of seconds for X number of times

```
x=0
n=60
while [ "$x" -lt 10 ]; do ./hello.o; ((x++));sleep $n; done
```

Comment: This will run `hello.o` once every 60 seconds forever.